# I have a ".txt "file which consists of various filenames and I want to search each filename in a folder where these files are actually kept

Tags: python

Suppose I have a text file `aiq_hits.txt`.
Each line in this file corresponds a filename

```
ant1.aiq
ant2.aiq
ant3.aiq
ant4.aiq
```

I want to match each line of my textfile (ant1.aiq,ant2.aiq and so on) with  filenames which are present at some specific place(`R:\Sample`) and extract matching files into some other place (`R:\sample\wsa`).

I have an idea that I need to use functions like `os.walk()` and `fnmatch.fnmatch()`, `shutil.copy()` but I am not able to implement them

My code:

```
import os
import shutil
import fnmatch

with open("aiq_hits.txt","r") as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
```

I am stuck here

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import shutil

sourceDir = "R:\\Sample"
targetDir = "R:\\Sample\\wsa"
existingFiles = set(f for f in os.listdir(sourceDir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(sourceDir, f)))
infilepath = "aiq_hits.txt"
with open(infilepath) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        fname = line.strip()
        if fname not in existingFiles: continue
        shutil.move(os.path.join(sourceDir, fname), os.path.join(targetDir, fname))
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will suffice:

```html
import os

def match_files(url,file_read, dest):
    f = open(file_read, 'rb')
    file_list = os.listdir(url)
    print(file_list)
    saved_path = os.getcwd()
    print("Current working directory is " + saved_path)
    os.chdir(url)
    match = []
    for file_name in f:
        file_name = file_name.strip()
        if file_name in file_list:
            match.append(file_name)
            os.rename(os.path.join(url, file_name), os.path.join(dest, file_name))
    os.chdir(saved_path) 
    print match
```

here, url is source directory or folder from which u want to match files, file_read is the name of file (with path) in which list of file names is given, dest is the destination folder.
this code moves the matching files from url to dest, i.e. these files won't remin in url after running the code.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use the glob module which allows you to enter in a expression for the file name\extension which will then return a list that you can loop over.
I'd use this module if the source directory can have files with the same extension that you want to exclude from being looped over

Also I'm assuming that the file name list is not large and so storing it in a list wont be an issue

eg (I haven't tested the below )

```
from glob import glob
import os
import shutil


src = 'R:\\Sample'
dst = "R:\\Sample\\wsa"
in_file_list = "aiq_hits.txt"

list_Of_files = glob(os.path.join(src, 'ant*.aiq'))
data = []

with open(in_file_list) as reader:
    data += reader.readlines()

for row in list_Of_files:
    file_path, file_name = os.path.split(row)
    if file_name in data:
        shutil.copy2(row, os.path.join(dst, file_name))
        # or if you want to move the file
        # shutil.move(row, os.path.join(dst, file_name))
```

Comment: @inspectorG4dget:  the code doesnt work.It doesnt give any error but it doesnt give output